# fcntl record lock works in multithreads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, filelock

I test multiprocess record lock with fcntl function, my current request needs to use record lock between threads.
I tested it, but it doesnot work as thought, do you have any suggestion on multithreads record locking?

Comment: What did you test? Show code please. And you could wrap your record accessing function with pthread mutex locks.